# Parallelise numerical integration with OpenMP in C++

Tags: c++, performance, numerical-methods, boost, openmp

I would like to parallelise with OpenMP a one-dimensional integral using the `integrate()` function implemented  in the Boost library. I found a rather obscure example (for my C++ skills) [in the Boost web site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/tutorial/parallel_computation_with_openmp_and_mpi.html).

I was wondering whether someone has experience with that, and may point out how I could implement this approach on my study case.

Also, do you think that the `for` loop within `PDFfunction()` could create problems in the parallelisation of the integral?

`PDFfunction()` represents the probability density function that is used
within the integrand function:

```
double PDFfunction(double invL, int t, double invtau, double x0, double x, int n_lim) {

const double c =  M_PI * (M_PI/4) * ((2 * t) * invtau);

double res = 0;

for(int n = 1; n <= n_lim; ++n){

  res += exp(-1 * (n * n) * c) * cos((n * M_PI * x) * invL) * cos((n * M_PI * x0) * invL);

}

return invL + ((2 * invL) * res);
}
```

`Composite_at_t()` is a function that makes use of `PDFfunction()` to compute `pbA` and `pbB`:

```
double Composite_at_t(double t, double B, double x0, double xt_pos, double y0, double yt_pos, double invLtot, double invtau, int n_lim) {

double pbA = PDFfunction(invLtot, t, invtau, x0, xt_pos, n_lim);
double pbB = PDFfunction(invLtot, t, invtau, y0, yt_pos, n_lim);
double b1 = 2 * (2 * t) * exp(-2 * t * B);
return pbA * pbB * b1;
}
```

`Composite_at_tCLASS` is a `Func` class which computes a first integral over variable `t`.

```
class Composite_at_tCLASS: public Func{
private:
    double B;
    double x0;
    double xt_pos;
    double y0;
    double yt_pos;
    double invLtot;
    double invtau;
    int n_lim;
public:
    Composite_at_tCLASS(double B_, double x0_, double xt_pos_, double y0_, double yt_pos_, double invLtot_, double invtau_, int n_lim_) : B(B_), x0(x0_), xt_pos(xt_pos_), y0(y0_), yt_pos(yt_pos_), invLtot(invLtot_), invtau(invtau_), n_lim(n_lim_) {}
    double operator()(const double& t) const{
        return Composite_at_t(t, B, x0, xt_pos, y0, yt_pos, invLtot, invtau, n_lim);
    }
};
```

`integrate_CompositeCLASS()` is the actual function that uses the class `Composite_at_tCLASS` and performs the integral over `t`, between `0` and `time_lim`.

```
double integrate_CompositeCLASS(double B, double x0, double xt_pos, double y0, double yt_pos, double invLtot, double invtau, int n_lim, double time_lim){

    Composite_at_tCLASS f(B, x0, xt_pos, y0, yt_pos, invLtot, invtau, n_lim);
    double err_est;
    int err_code;
    double res = integrate(f, 0, time_lim, err_est, err_code);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Variable `t` has a type `double` in `Composite_at_t` function, but `int` in `PDFfunction`. This may result in loss of significant digits, and there are unnecessary type conversions. A related comment is that it is a good practice not to use integer literals(/constants) in expressions to calculate a double type variable. To give an example `const double one_third=1/3;` is 0, because `1` and `3` are both integers, so the result of this integer division is zero, but `1.0/3.0` is 0.3333333...
2. Use `const` keyword wherever possible. It helps the compiler to better optimize the code. For more details please read e.g. [What kind of optimization does `const` offer in C/C++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27466642).
3. To parallelize with OpenMP the easiest solution is to put a `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res)` line in `PDFfunction` before the `for` loop. This is, however, not the best alternative, because you call `PDFfunction` twice in a row.
4. A better solution is to merge `Composite_at_t` and `PDFfunction`. In this case only one loop is needed. If you change the order of multiplications in line `res +=...` the `n * M_PI * invL` and `exp(-1.0 * (n * n) * c)` expressions are enough to calculate only once. I have also simplified some of your expressions (I hope I have not made any mistakes), so your `Composite_at_t` function should be something like:

```
double Composite_at_t(const double t, const double B, const double x0, const double xt_pos, const double y0, const double yt_pos, const double invLtot, const double invtau, const int n_lim) {

const double c =  0.5 * M_PI * M_PI * t * invtau;
const double b2 = 4.0 * invLtot * invLtot * t * exp(-2.0 * t * B);

double resx = 0;
double resy = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:resx, resy)
for(int n = 1; n <= n_lim; ++n){
  const double tmp1 = exp(-1.0 * (n * n) * c);
  const double tmp2 = M_PI * n * invLtot;  
  resx += tmp1 * cos(tmp2* xt_pos) * cos(tmp2 * x0);
  resy += tmp1 * cos(tmp2* yt_pos) * cos(tmp2 * y0);
}

return  b2 * (1.0 + 2.0 * resx) * (1.0 + 2.0 * resy);
}
```